# Падает push-функция в словаре при относительно большом объеме

Tags: c++, binary, дерево, словари

Пишу словарь на бинарном дереве. При небольших объемах все работает, но когда значения объема переваливает за 50к - программа падает. Не могу понять почему...
Это декоратор

```
void push(const std::string& k, T val)
{
    Node* e(new Node);
    e->key = k; e->value = val;
    e->left = e->right = nullptr;
    if (root) push(root, e);
    else root = e;
}
```

Метод который добавляет новый узел

```
void push(Node*& s, Node*& e)
{
    if (s) {
        if (s->key < e->key) push(s->right, e);
        else push(s->left, e);
    }
    else s = e;
}
```

вот [тут](https://pastebin.com/k8Qkuim3) код всего класса

Спасибо.

Comment: При такой реализации `void push(Node*& s, Node*& e)` нет никакой необходмости делать ветвление `if (root)` в первом методе. Однако неясно, зачем `e` передается по ссылке. Передача "по ссылкам" в всем коде представляет собой полнейший бардак без какой-либо логики. В методах `max` и `min` написан бред - неработоспособны. Метод `T& take(Node*& e, const std::string& k)` - не все пути возвращают значение.

Comment: Как выглядит вызывающий код? На какой именно строчке падает программа?

Comment: Может stack overflow?

Comment: @int3, да, именно переполнение стрека

Comment: @AnT спасибо за замечания.
Я думал, что передавая парламетр по ссылку избегу лишнего копирования.
Методы `max` и `min` переписал.
На счет `T& take(Node*& e, const std::string& k)` не совсем понятно.
Код падает именно в функции push - переполнение стека.

Comment: @Ant [здесь код всей программы](https://pastebin.com/gMhdevsA)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по комментариям и симптомам - падает из-за переполнения стека. Поменяйте рекурсию на цикл. Пример для `push`:

```
void push(Node*& s, Node* e)
{
    Node** head = &s;
    while (*head != nullptr) {
        head = ((*head)->key < e->key) ? &(*head)->right : &(*head)->left;
    }
    *head = e;
}
```

Comment: Приведенный Вами пример привод к бесконечному циклу

Comment: Опечатался, перепроверьте

Comment: спасибо. так же, я нашел альтернативное решение для своей проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так

```
void push(const std::string& k, T val)
{
    Node* e(new Node);
    e->key = k; e->value = val;
    e->left = e->right = nullptr;
    if (root) push(root, k) = e;
    else root = e;
}
Node*& push(Node*& s, const std::string& k)
{
    if (s) {
        if (s->key < k) push(s->right, k);
        else push(s->left, k);
    }
    else return s;
}
```

Comment: ??? И что это должно дать? Особенное если учесть, что программа падала из-за рекурсии...